# Show that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a polynomial $p(x)$ over $\Bbb Q$ such that $|f(x)-p(x^2)|<\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, continuity

> Let $f$ be a real valued continuous function on $[-1,1]$ such that $f(x)=f(-x)$ .Show that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a polynomial $p(x)$ over $\Bbb Q$ such that $|f(x)-p(x^2)|<\epsilon$

Since $f(x)$ is a continuous function by Weierstrass Approximation there exists a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $|f(x)-p(x)|<\epsilon$.

Also since $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ so we can take $p(x)$ over $\Bbb Q$ and still have $|f(x)-p(x)|<\epsilon$.

Now $f(x)=f(-x),  |f(-x)-p(-x)|<\epsilon\implies |f(x)-p(-x)|<\epsilon$

Thus we have  $|f(x)-p(x)|<\epsilon$,$|f(x)-p(-x)|<\epsilon,x\in [-1,1]$

How to combine these two to get $|f(x)-p(x^2)|<\epsilon$?
Please help.

Comment: I would reduce to the interval $[0,1]$, and use the slightly more general fact that approximation theorems of this type hold for any algebra of functions which separate points. On $[0,1]$, this is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply your reasoning to the function $f(\sqrt t)$ defined on the interval $[0,1]$.

You get that there exsists some polynomial $p\in\Bbb Q[t]$ such that $|p(t)-f(\sqrt t)|<\epsilon$ for $t\in[0,1]$.

Let $x=\sqrt t$. Since $x\in[0,1]\iff t\in[0,1]$, $|p(x^2)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for $x\in[0,1]$. And hence 
$$|p(x^2)-f(x)|=|p((-x)^2)-f(-x)|<\epsilon$$
for $x\in[-1,0]$.

Answer (score 1):

For the polynomial $p\;$ in your post, let 
$$q(x) = \frac{p(x)+p(-x)}{2}$$
Then $q\;$is a polynomial which satisfies the approximation.

But $q\;$is an even function.

A polynomial which is an even function can't have any nonzero odd power terms.